# Evitar un insert concurrente

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema en mi web. Resulta que tengo una tabla **packs** la cual tiene una columna **disponbilidad**. Un pack **estará disponible siempre y cuando la disponbilidad sea > 0**. Un usuario puede reservar un pack disponible, previo pago con Stripe.

Este formulario realizará un *INSERT* en la base de datos en la tabla **reservas**, comprobando antes que existen **packs disponibles**.

Al hacer un *INSERT* tengo un *trigger* que realiza un *UPDATE* sobre la tabla **packs** restando la columna **disponibilidad** en 1 unidad.

Sin embargo, a la hora de *reservar* un pack, si entran ***N*** peticiones al mismo tiempo, se realizará ***N*** *INSERT*, estos desencadenarán los ***N*** *UPDATES* y la disponibilidad acabará siendo -N valores. Tantos como reservas hayan entrado al mismo tiempo.

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se haga un INSERT de forma concurrente? Es decir, que cuando llega una petición no entre ninguna más.

Me interesa hacerlo por código PHP ya que quiero evitar que se realice el pago por parte del cliente en el caso de que la **disponibilidad** del **pack** sea 0.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un LOCK.  Este es un ejemplo sacado de la documentacion:

```
LOCK TABLES trans READ, customer WRITE;
SELECT SUM(value) FROM trans WHERE customer_id=some_id;
UPDATE customer
  SET total_value=sum_from_previous_statement
  WHERE customer_id=some_id;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Probada esta solución también y aunque le ponga a la tabla reservas el LOCK TABLES reservas WRITE; sigue dejándome hacer el INSERT.

Comment: Creo que en tu caso, primero tendrias que chequear si hay packs disponibles y si los hay primero haz el update de la columna disponibilidad.  Todo esto con un Lock en la tabla.  Esto asegurara que puedas hacer el Insert con confianza.  Si no hay disponibilidad, simplemente no hagas el Insert.

Comment: Correcto, solucionado con el LOCK table. Comentar que para usarlo en PHP con PDO es necesario usar [PDO::beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.begintransaction.php)

Answer (score 1):

Bajo mi punto de vista deberias **solo mostrar packs disponibles** al cliente en caso de que ya exista no mostrar(ocultarlos), otro punto seria que antes de hacer el **insert** primero realize un **select**  es decir primero consulte si esta disponible el pack o packs solo alli manda a realizar un insert y asu vez solo alli cobrarias ..!!
es decir tendrias 3 metodos:

- consultar si existen packs disponibles
- insertar el pack o pack seleccionados por el cliente
- cobrar el o los packs
  esa seria una opcion desde mi punto de vista !!
  suerte !!

Comment: El problema de esta solución es que, (si he entendido bien tu respuesta) si ambas transacciones llegan al mismo tiempo, ambas comprueban que hay packs disponibles al mismo tiempo, ambas insertan al mismo tiempo... etc. Por lo que necesito que una bloquee al resto hasta que acabe su transacción.